# Projection of CSV after converting geographic to planar coordinate system

Tags: coordinate-system, r, csv

I have a conceptual question. I have lat-long points which I have used to extract environmental variables from. My coordinates are in WGS1984. For most of the variables, I converted the environmental data into WGS1984 before extracting the data into a matrix/vector (Lat, Long + env variables).

For a few of the variables though, I increased efficiency by converting both my lat-long points and the environmental data into a planar coordinate system. Once I extracted the value for such environmental covariate, I added the values back to this data matrix.

I ran a regression on this data and now that I'm displaying the end result, I'm unsure whether it would be proper to label my data as WGS1984. I was planning on creating a raster out of this XYZ matrix and I have to list a projection in R. Would I have to retransform the extracted data in the planar projected data back in WGS1984 before I can add it into the data matrix? If I understand correctly, these are the environmental values that would correspond to data for the lat-long in either WGS or planar?

Comment: If you add the data back in before unprojecting, you'll have a corrupted dataset.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by a corrupted dataset? The data that I add back are simply just numerical values, with reasonable values in a range that I'd expect.

Comment: If the data needs projecting, it has a spatial component; if you merge data with different spatial references in one table, you destroy the ability to distinguish between objects' locations.

Comment: Thanks @Vince. To clarify then, this is all working in R: I've transformed pt1 (WGS1984) -->  pt1a (UTM) and extracting i.e. temperature in (UTM). I should now transform the dataframe of coordinates and temperature back into WGS1984 and add it to the original data matrix?